# Глагол перед местоимением

Tags: лексика

*Когда говорят:*
Сядь ты уже на стул
Купи ты себе айфон
Зачем ты веником подметаешь, купи ты себе пылесос —

это повелительное наклонение? Это вообще что?!

Answer (score 2):

*"Сядь", "купи"* — это повелительное наклонение, да. Инверсия с местоимением-подлежащим придаёт конструции окраску более императивную, чем без инверсии (сравните *подожди ты* и *ты подожди*). Какого-то особого названия для таких конструкций я не встречал.

Comment: Интересный материал на эту тему есть в Русской корпусной грамматике: 3.2 Выраженность подлежащего, 3.2.1.1 Подлежащее, выраженное личным местоимением ты / вы  http://rusgram.ru/Императив#31

Comment: Почему вы изменили ответ, там были интересные замечания по стилистике? В Грамматике тоже говорится: Местоимение присутствует, как правило, в конструкциях повышенной экспрессивности.

Comment: @Sharon мне так показалось лучше)

Comment: Там были ваши наблюдения, как вы это слышите. Это же самое ценное, а не то, что в книгах читано. Интересно, что они совпали с характеристикой  из статьи и при этом добавили что-то новое.